# jQuery $.ajax call -- strange return function issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a $.ajax call which looks as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#add_com_frm').submit(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var $btn_c = $('#add_com_but').button('loading');
            tinyMCE.triggerSave();

            var data = {
                "id": document.getElementById("id").value,
                "body": tinymce.get('body').getContent()
            };

            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
                url: 'https://something/test.php',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(msg,string,jqXHR) {
                    alert(msg.test);
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Now there's something strange, that I just can't explain logically.

PHP side:

```
 <?php
    $id = $filter->purify($_POST['id']);
    $body = $filter->purify($_POST['body']);

    $today = date('d.m.Y');
    $who = 'Someone';

    $result = $db->insert_com($id, $body, $who, $today);

    $list = array('test' => 'something');
    $c = json_encode($list);
    echo $c;
 ?>
```

Now, if I comment the line //$result = $db->insert [...] I got the alert from jQuery return msg.test, which is 'something' and that works, but for some strange reason when I un-comment that database related line, even if not directly related to that json being returned, it just doesn't work and no alert visible. I have no logical explanation for that, this line is somehow messing the json encode being returned when echo'ed, but why? and how? No idea!

Comment: Add an error handler to the Ajax call. See what the problem is

Comment: Hmz, 200, unexpected token < - any idea?

Comment: Check the response of the Ajax call in the network tab of the developer tools. It won't be valid JSON.

Comment: When I added xhr.responseText I see the entire html website, and {'test':true} at the same end of it.

Comment: Seems like the response header is: Content-Type:text/html, how to fix it?

Comment: Tried to add header('Content-Type: application/json'); but still, the entire html is being returned, and json at the end of it :/

Comment: well it is looking for JSON and it is returning html so the server is not returning what you expect. My guess is there an error message from the server being returned.

Comment: Strange is that it only happens when I got this line - $result = $db->insert_com($id, $body, $who, $today); -- if it's commented, then it works and returns 'something' string to the alert window. Whenever I un-comment it, problem occurs, and for some of the reason html is being returned. I changed the header to application/json, so now it's xhr, and json valid response, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Hm, I removed the Comment() object from the database class and it worked now, so in fact, even include_once to the Comment.php class, without using it, made this behave like this, cause Comment object returns some html to be inserted on the response. So if that's the case, as this is basically what I wanted to accomplish, do you guys maybe know how can I modify my return function to get that html Comment for appending?

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, so it appeared that the reason for that was that I have include_once to Comment class in my database handler. Rationale for that is based on the insertion I wanted to fulfill Comment object with new data, and return it as html. Do you maybe know how to modify my caller function to accept that html?